# upload picture and make it my css background-image

Tags: theming, media

I want to upload picture and make it my CSS background-image in Drupal? Is it possible?

Please reply if you know how thank you!

Comment: it is possible, but its hard to answer when we don't know your Drupal version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
hook_node_view($node, $viewmode, $langcode)
{
  if(count($node->field_background_image) && isset($node->field_backround_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']))
  {
    $node->content['#attached']['css'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'inline',
      'data' => '#some_div{background-image:url(' . file_create_url($node->field_background_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']) . ');}',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: im new in drupal! where can i code that in page.tpl?

Comment: No, you'll need to put it in a module, but it's a hook, so you cannot use it as-is. You'll have to spend some time learning on how to use Drupal hooks. This hook will only work in a module. You can also use hook_node_view_alter() and do a similar thing, and hook_node_view_alter() works in a theme too, not just a module.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the File Manager there is another way doing this.

1.I would go to /sites/default/files and upload the image there

(because that's were a lot of image from drupal get uploaded)

2.Then go over to the style-sheet (/sites/all/themes/*CURRENT_THEME*/css/style.css) through the file manager and edit it.
(*CURRENT THEME* being the folder of the theme you have active)

3.Add this code:

```
body {
background: url("http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-mosaic-background.png");
background-color: #cccccc;
/* background color is there color it shows until the image loads or if a user has images disabled. */
}
```

Hope this helps.